# Как нарисовать ячейку?

Tags: android

Имеется такая вот картинка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно нарисовать ячейки для букв. Не помню как называется стиль, но по моему `Inner`, когда ячейка вогнута во внутрь. И дело в том, что не дружу с `Фотошоп` для рисования и использовать с `9-Patch`. В просторах интернета не нашел(или не правильно искал).

Так вот вопрос в том, как в `Drawable` нарисовать такую кнопку или ячейку?